# OncheckChanged not Firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I have a working page but now I recreated it and it doesn't work. I need some help to figure out why.

The way it should work is when I check the checkbox and click a button it should fire the checkbox function and then the button function

Working code
asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuoteLine") %>' OnCheckedChanged="QuoteLine_CheckedChanged" ForeColor="Transparent" Font-Size="0.1" />
```

Codebhind

```
Private SelectLines As New List(Of String)

Protected Sub QuoteLine_CheckedChanged(sender As CheckBox, e As EventArgs)
       If sender.Checked Then
           SelectLines.Add(sender.Text)
           'selectedLines = SelectLines
       End If
End Sub

Protected Sub BPrehang_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BPrehang.Click
        Session.Remove("Type")
        Session.Remove("Location")
        Session.Remove("Quote")

        If SelectLines IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each Item In SelectLines
                If Item IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim QuoteLine = Applications.QuoteLine.GetQuoteLineByLineId(Item)

                    If QuoteLine IsNot Nothing Then
                        Response.Redirect("../New-Pages/NewPrehangConfiguration.aspx?QuoteNumberId=" & TQuoteNumber.Text & "&PrehangId=" & QuoteLine.PrehangListId)

                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Response.Redirect("../New-Pages/NewPrehangConfiguration.aspx?QuoteNumberId=" & TQuoteNumber.Text)
End Sub
```

Not working Code

Asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderLine")%>' OnCheckedChanged="OrderLine_CheckedChanged" ForeColor="Transparent" Font-Size="0.1" />
```

Code Behind

```
Private SelectLines As New List(Of String)

  Protected Sub OrderLine_CheckedChanged(sender As CheckBox, e As EventArgs)
        If sender.Checked Then
            SelectLines.Add(sender.Text)
            'selectedLines = SelectLines
        End If
    End Sub

 Protected Sub BPrehang_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BPrehang.Click
        Session.Remove("Type")
        Session.Remove("Location")
        Session.Remove("Order")
        Session.Add("Prehang", "True")

        If SelectLines IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each Item In SelectLines
                If Item IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim Order = Applications.OrderLine.GetOrderByOrderLine(Item)

                    If Order IsNot Nothing Then
                        Response.Redirect("../New-Pages/NewPrehangConfiguration.aspx?OrderNumber=" & TOrderNumber.Text & "&PrehangId=" & Order.PrehangListId, False)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Response.Redirect("../New-Pages/NewPrehangConfiguration.aspx?OrderNumber=" & TOrderNumber.Text, False)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try setting AutoPostBack to true, but this will refresh the page too. So you need to handle that page event.

Comment: I Can't do that because it wouldn't hold my value in the variable called "SelectedLines" I know I can put the value in a temp textbox but how come it works in the first and not the second piece of code?